# Execute php using exec() not working

Tags: php, command-line, amazon-s3

I am trying to execute a shell command from php command line in following way

```
php -r '$test = exec("aws s3 cp s3://test/my-container/testing.txt /var/www/files-test"); echo $test;'
```

this works and as result files get downloaded from s3 to mentioned destination `/var/www/files-test`

But when I execute same command from web app it does not work. Code is

```
$test = exec("aws s3 cp s3://test/my-container/testing.txt /var/www/files-test");
print_r($test);
```

it does not work and as output I got

> Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining

I have ensured apache user has required privileges. What can be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved, web-server I am using was nginix and web app some how was running on apache user, I gave permissions for nginix user but not for apache user!

so fix was to get back the app to run on nginix user.